# How to use save() method for create and update in Eloquent?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, orm

I have this object in form of array:

```
[{"id":"2","passport_number":"AB-2019-11-24-0200","place_issue":"Yuan","date_issue":"2018-10-10","date_expiry":"2018-10-10"}]
```

and i am trying to save it via `save()` method of laravel eloquent, here is how it looks:

```
private function save_person_passport($object, $person_id, \App\Passport $passport){
    if($object->id > 0){
        $passport->id = $object->id;
    }
    $passport->person_id = $person_id;
    $passport->passport_number = $object->passport_number;
    $passport->place_issue = $object->place_issue;
    $passport->date_issue = $object->date_issue;
    $passport->date_expiry = $object->date_expiry;

    $passport->save(); 
}
```

I am wondering why i am getting this error:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '2' for key 'PRIMARY' (SQL: insert into `passports`
```

Isn't **save()** method use for **create** and **update**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating a new instance of `\App\Passport` so it'll save the record not update. You may do one thing find the id if `$object->id > 0`

Replace your code the same as below I mention will work for you.

```
if($object->id > 0){
    $passport = \App\Passport::find($object->id);
    $passport->id = $object->id;
}
$passport->person_id = $person_id;
$passport->passport_number = $object->passport_number;
$passport->place_issue = $object->place_issue;
$passport->date_issue = $object->date_issue;
$passport->date_expiry = $object->date_expiry;

$passport->save();
```

Now if `$object->id > 0` then it'll find the collection of `Passport`. And update the record which primary key is `2`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
private function save_person_passport($object, $person_id, \App\Passport $passport){
if($object->id > 0){
    $passport = \App\Passport::find($object->id);
      if(!empty($passport){
        $passport->person_id = $person_id;
        $passport->passport_number = $object->passport_number;
        $passport->place_issue = $object->place_issue;
        $passport->date_issue = $object->date_issue;
        $passport->date_expiry = $object->date_expiry;
        $passport->save(); 
      }
    } 
 }
```